# how to set value environment variable as array in docker run

Tags: docker

I want to set value of environment variable as array,

```
docker run --name gitlab-server -d --env 'ip_whitelist=array_value'
```

how to do that?

I expectation my result like this :

```
 ip_whitelist: ["127.0.0.1","123.456.7.0/24"]
```

thanks for help

Comment: sooo `'ip_whitelist=["127.0.0.1","123.456.7.0/24"]'` ?

Comment: In Unix in general, environment variables are only strings.  Whatever way you need the array to be formatted, put it inside the `docker run -e` option.